# compact framework design time support from external dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, mobile, compact-framework

I know this has been asked before, and also there are answers which solves the problem partially. I've some user controls which we use in our warehouse mobile application framework, and to get design-time support I use DesktopCompatible custom arrtibute in DesignTimeAttibutes.xmta file.

This solves the problem if both the library and the UI project is in the same solution. For example I have this solution layout :

- Company.Mobile (Solution)

  - Company.Mobile.Library (Project) this has DesignTimeAttributes.xmta
  - Company.Mobile.Project1 (Project)

- Company.Mobile.Project2 (Solution)

  - Company.Mobile.Project2 (Project)

So when I reference Company.Mobile.Library from Company.Mobile.Project1 I have design-time support for the controls, but not from Company.Mobile.Project2. I also tried to copy xmta file to Project2 but still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks @ymc.cu, this little info solves my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides having your library dll, you should also have an extra dll called yourlibrarydll.asmmeta.dll. Try coping this dll into the output folder of your Project2.